# Vue.js CLI can't change default HOST

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

I can't change the default HOST when trying to set a new environment variable like the following:

```
SET HOST=custom.localhost
SET PORT=8081
npm run dev
```

The error: `activeevents.js:182 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event`

If I run without set new environment variables i.e using the default HOST `localhost` and default PORT `8080` the `npm run dev` doesn't catch any error and the application works like a charm.

> I haven't any other HOST like 'custom.localhost' running on my system.
>
> The problem isn't with PORT because I can change it to any other without any problem.

```
Vue.js version: 2.5.2
Vue.js CLI version: 2.9.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to create a custom **Virtual Host** on your system before, because if not have yet the CLI will catch an error like above and another error: `Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND custom.localhost`

So, after doing that the application will work!